# TypeORM FindById doesn't work with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, typeorm

I'm trying to use TypeORM with MongoDB and express but I'm having problems with the basic stuff.

I just created a controller with basic CRUD operations for an entity. The methods save, findAll and find by Filter works ok, but I can't make the methods that require an mongo id work.

```
router.get("/", async(req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const investmentRepository = getMongoRepository(Investment);

    const investments = await investmentRepository.find();
    res.send(investments);
});

router.get("/:id", async(req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const investmentRepository = getMongoRepository(Investment);
    const investment = await 
    investmentRepository.findOneById(req.params.id);
    if (!investment) {
        res.status(404);
        res.end();
    }
    res.send(investment);
});
```

The second method is always returning 404.
For example, this is an entity returned on get all "investment/"

```
{
    "id": "59dfd8cadcbd9d1720457008",
    "name": "Teste LCI",
    "startDate": 1466305200,
    "numberOfDays": 365,
    "type": "LCI_LCA"
}
```

If I try to send a request for this specific object calling

> investment/59dfd8cadcbd9d1720457008

the response is always 404.

The same behavior happen with the delete method, raising an exception

> Cannot find entity to remove by a given id

I also tried to convert the string to ObjectID using:

```
new ObjectID(req.params.id);
```

but it fails with the error ObjectID is not a constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're receiving the error ObjectId is not a constructor it is because you forgot to require it in your file. All you need is:

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
```

Comment: Thanks, I could make it work importing mongodb.

    `import * as mongodb from "mongodb";`

    `new mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.id);`

I don`t know why ObjectID from typeorm package doesnt work.

Comment: Because it's just `declare abstract class` for typings, not for runtime purpose.
In new release you will be able to find by id which is hex string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing from typeorm that might occur, you need to use:

```js
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb'
```

Here is an example :

```js
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TaskStatus } from './task-status.enum';
import { CreateTaskDto} from './dto/create-task.dto';
import { GetTasksFilterDto } from './dto/get-tasks-filter.dto';
import { TaskRepository } from './dto/task.respository';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Task } from './entities/task.entity';
import { ObjectId} from 'mongodb';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Task)
    private tasksRepository: TaskRepository
  )
  {}

  async getTaskById(id: ObjectId): Promise<Task> {
    console.log(`Finding task with id '${id}'`);
    const found = await this.tasksRepository.findOne({
      where: { _id: new ObjectId(id) }
    });

    console.log(found);
    if (!found) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`The task with '${id}' does not exist`);
    }
    return found;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, this is a different example; a better answer should adapt (or fix) the original code, Giving a totally different subject doesn't help much